# What is the origin of System::Process.new?

Tags: ruby, god

Where is the origin of `Process.new` and where is it doccumented? I have looked in the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html) at the process module and I cannot figure out how this is declared.

The code I am trying to replicate is in the Ruby God gem in [lib/god/conditions/memory_usage.rb:66](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/v0.12.1/lib/god/conditions/memory_usage.rb#L66):

```
process = System::Process.new(self.pid)
@timeline.push(process.memory)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System::Process` isn't part of Ruby, it comes from God (the gem) itself. You can [view its source](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/v0.12.1/lib/god/system/process.rb) if you want.

It's referable as `System::Process` in the file you reference because you're already in the `God` module, so Ruby resolves it within that namespace.